# Make child flexbox container scrollable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I want to use a full-height app using flexbox, white area which is a flex item needs to be scrollable in my case, however it doesn't seem to be working, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/644/).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #999999;
}
.context {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header style='background: red; flex: 0 0 auto'>
  This is Mmain header
</header>
<main style='background: green; flex: 1 0 auto; display:flex;'>
  <div class='left'>
    left pannel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
    <div class='context'>
      <div style='height: 3000px;'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

How can I make the white area scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### #1 - With `position: absolute`

An easy way to prevent the extra long div from stretching its parent is to make it `position: absolute` and relative to its `.context` parent.

- The `body` is given `100vh` and the `main` is given an inital height of `100%` which will shrink to fit the body evenly
- The header is given `flex: 0 0 25px` so will remain its fixed height

#### Working Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 25px;
}
main {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #999999;
  margin: 10px;
}
.context {
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}
.context > div {
  height: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is main header
</header>
<main>
  <div class='left'>
 left panel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
 <div class='sub-header'>
   This is sub header
 </div>
 <div class='context'>
   <div>
  Super long div
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

### #2 - Original - Flexible heights

Main points:

- The header and main elements don't need to be flex children of body. They can be controlled with flexible heights.
- Give the `header` and `main` a height in [viewport height units (`vh`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths). Make sure that the height of header + main = 100
- `.context` gets `overflow-y: scroll`. None of the other elements require an overflow property
- `.context` and `.sub-header` have the flex property removed in this example. If the flex property is used, don't have an initial value of `auto` on the context div, **otherwise the overflow scroll will break** and spill outside the viewport.

#### Working Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background: red;
  height: 10vh;
}
main {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #999999;
  margin: 10px;
}
.context {
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
}
.context > div {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is main header
</header>
<main>
  <div class='left'>
 left panel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
 <div class='sub-header'>
   This is sub header
 </div>
 <div class='context'>
   <div>
  Super long div
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Seems I have to put a `explicit height` to `main` rather than use `flex: 1 0 auto` to auto stretch the available space of its parents.

Comment: Do you think is it possible to scroll the `context` zone without put an explicit height to both `header` and `main`, which means `header -> flex: 0 0 auto`, `main -> flex:1 0 auto` ?

Comment: The thing is i'm using a boostrap navbar component in the header, if I have to put an explicit height to the header I need to measure the `height` of this `navbar` component, also if I'll put some further stuffs below the `navbar` in `header` I have to calculate all the margins, paddings and heights manually to adjust the height of the header.

Comment: @Z.Neeson - [Test this one out](https://jsbin.com/novosa/edit?html,css,output). The super long div is `position: absolute` and all its parents play nicely.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution #1 which should address those issues.

Comment: That's fantastic! it indeed addressed my issue, it shouldn't have browser compatibility issue in modern browsers right? also would you please give a little bit explanation why `position: absolute` would play the trick?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your updates in your post, thanks again.

Comment: @Z.Neeson - No worries :) Basically, by making the extra long div `position: absolute`, it is removed from the normal flow of the document and no longer has any affect on other elements which now ignore it.

Comment: This will work [anywhere that modern flexbox works](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Need to Change CSS : `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of `overflow-y: auto;`

Comment: This doesn't take any difference.